# Chart not showing all data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have created a very simple spreadsheet with data by half an hour for every day from Mon - Fri.

I have then created a line chart and in the legend every day is shown, however the data for Monday is not visible.

The data is different from other days and therefore does not overlap so this isn't the issue. If I create a bar chart, vertical or horizontal the data DOES show.

I'm totally stumped as to why this should be.

The line colour does not clash with the background and if I select data then the range is showing. Anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That effect is occurring because the columns "Monday" and "Friday" are exactly identical in your data. A two-dimensional line chart is thus not suitable if you want to see all five days. The line for "Monday" is "hidden" behind the line for "Friday". It is not a bug, but results from selecting this kind of chart for identical data series.

Also, check out this question: [Excel chart does not show all line feeds](https://superuser.com/questions/385112/excel-chart-does-not-show-all-line-feeds?rq=1). It has a nicely illustrated answer.

Comment: Doh!!!! I would consider myself a very competent user of Excel and i just didn't spend enough time looking at the data. Thanks he said as he walked away with his head hung in shame :-)